# io.restassured.path.json.exception.JsonPathException: Failed to parse the JSON document

Tags: testng

```
[RemoteTestNG] detected TestNG version 7.8.0
FAILED: files.Dynamic.addBook
io.restassured.path.json.exception.JsonPathException: Failed to parse the JSON document
    at io.restassured.path.json.JsonPath$ExceptionCatcher.invoke(JsonPath.java:1002)
    at io.restassured.path.json.JsonPath$4.doParseWith(JsonPath.java:967)
    at io.restassured.path.json.JsonPath$JsonParser.parseWith(JsonPath.java:1047)
    at io.restassured.path.json.JsonPath.get(JsonPath.java:202)
    at files.Dynamic.addBook(Dynamic.java:21)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
    at org.testng.internal.invokers.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:139)
    at org.testng.internal.invokers.TestInvoker.invokeMethod(TestInvoker.java:664)
    at org.testng.internal.invokers.TestInvoker.invokeTestMethod(TestInvoker.java:227)
    at org.testng.internal.invokers.MethodRunner.runInSequence(MethodRunner.java:50)
    at org.testng.internal.invokers.TestInvoker$MethodInvocationAgent.invoke(TestInvoker.java:957)
    at org.testng.internal.invokers.TestInvoker.invokeTestMethods(TestInvoker.java:200)
    at org.testng.internal.invokers.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:148)
    at org.testng.internal.invokers.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:128)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1511)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:848)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:621)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:443)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:437)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:397)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:336)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:95)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1280)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1200)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuites(TestNG.java:1114)
    at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1082)
    at org.testng.remote.AbstractRemoteTestNG.run(AbstractRemoteTestNG.java:115)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:251)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:77)
Caused by: groovy.json.JsonException: Lexing failed on line: 1, column: 1, while reading 'h', no possible valid JSON value or punctuation could be recognized.
    at groovy.json.JsonLexer.nextToken(JsonLexer.java:86)
    at groovy.json.JsonLexer$nextToken.call(Unknown Source)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:45)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:125)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:130)
    at io.restassured.internal.path.json.ConfigurableJsonSlurper.parse(ConfigurableJsonSlurper.groovy:97)
    at io.restassured.internal.path.json.ConfigurableJsonSlurper$parse.callCurrent(Unknown Source)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCallCurrent(CallSiteArray.java:49)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:171)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:185)
    at io.restassured.internal.path.json.ConfigurableJsonSlurper.parseText(ConfigurableJsonSlurper.groovy:83)
    at io.restassured.path.json.JsonPath$4$1.method(JsonPath.java:965)
    at io.restassured.path.json.JsonPath$ExceptionCatcher.invoke(JsonPath.java:1000)
    ... 32 more

====================

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>log4j-slf4j-impl</artifactId>
    <version>2.20.0</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Hi @poorna pragna
The exception stack trace indicates that there's an issue with the JSON document's structure, which is preventing it from being parsed correctly
Please can you share the example JSON structure